# Android - WebService connectivity loss

Tags: android, web-services, apache-axis, connectivity

I have developed an Android application, with a Backend server support.
The server is writteng in Java/Axis2/Hibernate.

I have encoutered a strange situation...
Sometimes the Android device connectivity with the server is lost, but the issue is that I can see in the server logs that the related WebService API is being executed, therefore packet recieved in the server, but the response is not received in the Android device.

I want to eliminate the worst-case scenario that the problem is in the Server.

Any ideas how can I do it?
Maybe someone had the same problem?

Yoav

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to guarantee that the response is sent to the device successfully or avoid executing the request queries which cant be replied?